# Does the Javascript 'for-in' function, return just an index?

Tags: javascript

This is a method I tried to run:

```
function SayHello() {
    cars = new Array();
    cars[0] = "Toyota";
    cars[1] = "Mitsubishi";
    cars[2] = "Honda";

    for (car in cars) {
        alert(car);
    }
}
```

This returned:

```
0
1
2
```

When I changed the code to this:

```
function SayHello() {
    cars = new Array();
    cars[0] = "Toyota";
    cars[1] = "Mitsubishi";
    cars[2] = "Honda";

    for (car in cars) {
        alert(cars[car]);
    }
}
```

It returned the names correctly.

My question is, does the for-in loop just return an index in an orderly fashion? Thanks.

Comment: The simple answer is: The for-in return the name of the properties of the object you are iterating. In this case, when you say cars[0] = instead of cars.push(...) you are creating a property which name is 0. To iterate through the values you would need a for(var i=0;i<cars.length;i++) alert(cars[i]);

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it will be the index within the collections.

See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```
var mycars = ["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"];

for (var car in mycars)
{
  document.write(mycars[car] + "<br />");
}
```

As you can see, the use of the variable as an index into the collection.

You can use `for each ... in` syntax (introduced in Javascript 1.6) that *will* iterate over values. See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Archive/Web/JavaScript/for_each...in).

> `for each...in` - similar to `for...in`, but iterates over the values of object's properties, rather than the property names themselves. (New in JavaScript 1.6.)

As far as I know, Javascript 1.6+ is only used in Firefox at this time.

Comment: Bad answer... 1. `var x` at the top is stupid in JS 2. use `["Saab", "Volvo", "BMW"]` for creating an Array, the `Array` constructor should be avoided (take a look at what parameters it takes) 3. The usual missing `hasOwnProperty` in the `for...in`

Comment: @Oded Which only further undermines the credibility of this answer - when did W3School become the leading authority on learning JavaScript?

Comment: @Oded Oh sorry, missed point 4. Link to w3schools. That alone is worth a down vote from everyone here :/

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel - The example was taken, verbatim from w3schools. Can you explain what you mean by your third point about `hasOwnProperty`, or add a link to a good explanation?

Comment: @Oded `for...in` also lists things that are on the prototype chain. `Object.prototype.foo = 2`, now foo will be listed by every `for...in`. `hasOwnProperty` will check whether the property is actually defined on an object. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/HasOwnProperty

Comment: @Ivo Wetzel - Fair enough. I don't understand your point about it missing from the loop - that's what I wanted explained, not what the function does. Regardless, I _can't_ delete this answer, as it has been accepted...

Comment: @Oded: IE9 => `SCRIPT1005: Expected '('`, so IE9 - no dice, sorry.

Comment: @Kooilnc - OK... I saw that in an incorrect source in that case.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, the value of the iterator is the name of the property. It's highly frowned upon to use it to loop over arrays, however. For example, consider this:

```
x = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

x.foo = 'bar';

for (i in x) alert(i);  // 0, 1, 2, foo
```

It's intended for iterating over the members of an object:

```
x = { a : 'apple', b : 'banana', c : 'carrot' };

for (i in x) {
    // and it's best to check that the property actually exists
    // on this object, not just on one of its prototypal ancestors:
    if (x.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
        alert(i);  // 'a', 'b', 'c'
    }
}
```

More information about why on the [YUI Blog](https://web.archive.org/web/20061102165520/https://yuiblog.com/blog/2006/09/26/for-in-intrigue/)

Comment: isn't javascript weird? :D

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. It returns indexes, not the values, and it returns them as quoted strings. "0", "1", etc..

The plus side of this is that `for in` works the same if you use a javascript object as associative array.

Answer (score 1):

It returns the "key" of each item. Same result will be achieved with such "array":

```
cars = {0: "Toyota", 1: "Mitsubishi", 2: "Honda"};
```

Answer (score 1):

use the regular for...

```
for (var i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
   let car = cars[i];
   // Do what you want from here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[for...in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) - iterates over all enumerable properties of an object that are keyed by strings (**for simple arrays it returns the element's index**).

[for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) - **iterates over the property values** but can only be used for iteratable types: built-in String, Array, array-like objects (e.g., arguments or NodeList), TypedArray, Map, Set, and user-defined iterables (not for generic objects).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for value, then use `of` as below:

```
var cars = ["Toyota", "Mitsubishi", "Honda"];

console.log('-- in --');
for (car in cars) {
    console.log(car);
}

console.log('-- of --');
for (car of cars) {
    console.log(car);
}
```

Output:

```
-- in --
0
1
2
-- of --
Toyota
Mitsubishi
Honda
```