# Drawing many lines with GoogleMaps API

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to use the JavaScript API for GoogleMaps to draw a bunch of lines but I keep getting syntax errors I don't understand.  My data is stored as such:

```
var line_map = {};
line_map['l1'] = {
  path: [new google.maps.LatLng(42.3581, -71.0636), new google.maps.LatLng(42.351821, -71.045461)],
  weight: 2
};
```

With many other line entries.  I then try to use it with the following:

```
for (var entry in line_map) {
    var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: entry.path,
      geodesic: true,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 1.0,
      strokeWeight: entry.weight
    });

    // Add the line to map
    line.setMap(map);
  }
```

However I keep getting an error that says `Invalid value for constructor parameter 0: undefined`

I get that it's saying entry.path is undefined but I don't understand why because I clearly defined it in the entry for `l1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should change this:

`path: entry.path`

to

`path: line_map[entry].path`

And do the same with the `weight`. Check out [this working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pascal_/7UpQZ/) - I changed some coordinates to see the line.

EDIT: There is also a good explanation on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4534496/2327005) about the for...in loop and objects.